# Converting general form to standard form in linear programming

Tags: mathematical-statistics, optimization, model, linear-programming

I am new to linear programming and I am currently trying to convert a general LP problem to standard form. The general form the problem is as follows:

I have the following objective function, in which I am supposed to minimize for $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$:

$z=2x_1 +5x_2$ such that

$x_1 \geq 5$

$x_1 + x_2\leq 9$

$-2x_1 + x_2 = -4$

$x_1,x_2 \geq 0$

In order to convert to standard form, I used surplus and slack variables (denoted as $s_1$ and $s_2$, respectively) as need and moved the -4 to the right hand side. In standard form, I got the following:

$z=2x_1 +5x_2$ such that

$x_1 - s_1 = 5$

$x_1 + x_2 + s_2 = 9$

$-2x_1 + x_2 + 4 = 0$

$x_1,x_2, s_1, s_2 \geq 0$

I just wanted to clarify if my way of approaching this problem is correct, or if there is anything that I need to do more in order to convert to standard form (I am especially confused about the -4 for some reason).

Comment: Your last equality should have the $-4$ on the right hand side, otherwise looks good!

Comment: Both original and standard form are valid linear programs that could be input to computer software so you could run both and see if they produce consistent results as a check.